# Core Data Fetch To Many

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data

I am trying to fetch all categories, and their sub categories, and display them all in a table.  I know how to fetch all categories, but I need to fetch all sub categories, and sort them by category using a fetch results controller.  Any ideas of suggestions?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a fetched results controller that fetches *SubCategory* entities and groups them into sections according to the *Category*:

```
// Fetch "SubCategory" entities:
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"SubCategory"];

// First sort descriptor for grouping the cells into sections, sorted by category name:
NSSortDescriptor *sort1 = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"category.name" ascending:YES];
// Second sort descriptor for sorting the cells within each section:
NSSortDescriptor *sort2 = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
request.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:sort1, sort2, nil];

self.fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc]
                                        initWithFetchRequest:request
                                        managedObjectContext:context
                                          sectionNameKeyPath:@"category.name"
                                                   cacheName:nil];

[self.fetchedResultsController setDelegate:self];
NSError *error;
BOOL success = [self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error];
```

Then you can use the usual table view data source methods as described in the [NSFetchedResultsController Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

This gives you a table view with one table view section for each category.

Answer (score 1):

so, you have the categories in the **fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects**

since each **subCategory** is essentially contained in the **Category** you can access each by calling `[Category valueForKey:@"subCategory"`

this will give you an NSSet that you can then sort out (to an NSArray) and use as data for your tableView.

It won't be contained in a fetchedResultsController though.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the option u can do it in other way also if u like.

Take all The Category objects in arrayOfCategories

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection (NSInteger)section:


{
    Category *cat = [ arrayOfCategories objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]

   if(arrayToHoldObjects.count > 0)

{

[arrayToHoldObjects removeAllObject];
}


for(Subcategory *sub in Category.subcategory)

{
   [arrayToHoldObjects addObject:sub];

}

  return arrayToHoldObjects.count;


}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


  Category *cat = [ arrayOfCategories objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]

   if(arrayToHoldObjects.count > 0)

{

[arrayToHoldObjects removeAllObject];
}


for(Subcategory *sub in Category.subcategory)

{
   [arrayToHoldObjects addObject:sub];

}

   Subcategory *sub = [arrayToHoldObjects objectAtIndexPath.row]  

   for(int k =0 ; k < arrayToHoldObjects .count; k++)
  {

    // do what ever u like with sub  

     return cell;

   }



}
```